# Workbox Precaching / RuntimeCaching hybrid

Tags: progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have converted my app into a PWA with workbox, and using the precaching strategy

Right now I reload the page when the workbox worker has finished refetching the cache

```js
// Register service worker extract
import { register } from 'register-service-worker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
    updatefound() {
      // New content is downloading.
    },
    updated() {
      // New content is available; refresh.
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload(true);
      }, 500);
    },
  });
}
```

```js
// Service worker extract
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching/precacheAndRoute';
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
self.skipWaiting();
```

But I find it really bothering to have a stale version for 2-5 seconds and then the page reloaded with the new version

What I would like to achieve, is RuntimeCaching when an update is found, the new files are used directly instead of refetching the cache in the background

Is there a way to configure workbox for that, so that I can reload the page straight away

```js
// Register service worker extract
    updatefound() {
       window.location.reload(true);
    },
    updated() {
      
    },
```

And the worbox worker will not serve the cache on the reloaded page and instead make the network requests on the fly, basically a Precaching and RuntimeCaching hybrid to get the best of both worlds?

I couldn't find anything that achieves that anywhere

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is using a `NetworkFirst` strategy, along with optionally "[warming](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-recipes#warm_strategy_cache)" the runtime cache with the content that you want to make sure is available offline.

Precaching, with its cache-first approach to serving content, doesn't sound like an appropriate solution to your use case.